# How to understand "if the base image is already in the cache it is reused."?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> If the base image is already in the cache it is reused.

Is that means

"**if** the base image is already in the cache, **then** it is reused."?

Which grammar knowledge should I learn further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intepretation is correct

> If x, then y

means the same as

> If x, y

The punctuation in the sentence you quoted is not standard: usually a comma is inserted between an initial hypothetical clause and a following consequent clause. Except for the missing comma, the sentence you quoted is grammatical and idiomatic.

However, the structure of noun ... noun... pronoun, where the pronoun refers to the first rather than immediately preceding noun, is not the clearest way to write. Better rhetorically would be

> The base image will be reused if it is already in the cache

If, for some reason, the hypothetical should come first, I might change the verb, for example

> If the cache already holds the base image, it will be reused

These last two examples are not corrections of grammar; they represent my opinion about what is clearer writing.

Comment: For technical writing, use of "it" in both of the improvements might still be ambiguous. Tests like SAT really harp on this point. Most speakers/writers fall into the trap that the listener/reader will automatically know what the pronouns refer to. For utmost clarity, one might use "If the cache already holds the base image, the image from cache will be reused."

Comment: "Then" is a bit redundant. "If" is a sufficient descriptor of condition. See [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307510/is-it-necessary-to-use-then-in-the-second-main-clause-of-a-conditional-sentenc?noredirect=1&lq=1) for some more discussion.'